# Why deinit is not called when I pop/self.dismiss my WKInterfacecontroller

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit

I am fetching user location, I have created singleton class to fetch user location when it required. but it is creating retain cycle. and deint not called if I use LocationManager class. if I do not use this class this de
init is properly called as expected.

```
class LocationManager: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate  {
private var clLocationManager: CLLocationManager?
private var SuccessBlock:((_ latitude: String, _ longitude: String)->Void)?
private var OnFailedBlock:(()->Void)?
private var lat: String?
private var long: String?

static let shared: LocationManager = {
    let instance = LocationManager()
    return instance
}()

private override init() {
    super.init()
}


private  func invokeLocationManager() {

    if self.clLocationManager == nil {

        self.clLocationManager =  CLLocationManager()
        self.clLocationManager?.delegate = self
    }

    self.clLocationManager?.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    self.clLocationManager?.startUpdatingLocation()
}


func getUserCurrentLocation(onSucessBlok onSucessBlock:@escaping (_ lat: String, _ long: String)->Void, onFailedBlok onFailedBlock:@escaping ()->Void) ->Void {

    self.SuccessBlock = onSucessBlock
    self.OnFailedBlock = onFailedBlock
    self.invokeLocationManager()
}



func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    self.clLocationManager?.stopUpdatingLocation()
    if locations.count > 0 {

        let userLocation = locations[0]
         self.long = String(userLocation.coordinate.longitude);
         self.lat = String(userLocation.coordinate.latitude);

        if self.SuccessBlock != nil {

            self.SuccessBlock!(self.lat!, self.long!)
            self.SuccessBlock = nil
        }

    } else {

        if self.OnFailedBlock != nil {

            self.OnFailedBlock!()
            self.OnFailedBlock = nil
        }
    }
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {

    if self.OnFailedBlock != nil {

        self.OnFailedBlock!()
        self.OnFailedBlock = nil
    }
}
}
```

> From WKInterfaceController, I am calling this method

```
override func willActivate() {
    super.willActivate()
   self.getUserLocation()
}

private func getUserLocation() {

    LocationManager.shared.getUserCurrentLocation(onSucessBlok: { [weak self] (lat, long) in

        if CommonHelper.isStringValid(string: lat) && CommonHelper.isStringValid(string: long) {

            self?.fillInfoToDictionary(value:lat, key: KLatitude, type: InfoType.Acceleration)
            self?.fillInfoToDictionary(value:long, key: KLongitude, type: InfoType.Acceleration)

        }

    }, onFailedBlok: {


        self.fillInfoToDictionary(value:"0", key: KLatitude, type: InfoType.Acceleration)
        self.fillInfoToDictionary(value:"0", key: KLongitude, type: InfoType.Acceleration)
    })
}
```

I call this getUserCurrentLocation method every time when WKInterface's willActivate is called. 
is there any other better way to do this? so that retain cycle will not create.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing seems to be wrong in the `LocationManager` class itself, but you're holding a strong reference to `onSuccessBlock` and `onFailedBlock` that is passed in the `getUserCurrentLocation` function that you're calling from your `WKINterfaceController` class. If you're retaining `self` in those blocks, the `LocationManager` will have a strong reference to your `WKInterfaceController` class, thus the `deinit` won't be called. Could you put the code of your `WKInterfaceController`? Then we can say more.

EDIT: Yep, you're capturing `self` as `weak` in the `onSuccessBlock`, but strongly in the `onFailedBlock`. If you put `[weak self] in` statement at the start of the `onFailedBlock` it should work.

Comment: so what is best way to make blocks variable weak or is this necessary to make blocks as. weak.

Comment: You have to hold a strong reference to the blocks in your `LocationManager` class because if you don't, these blocks will be released as nothing else is holding a strong reference to them. As a rule of thumb you should always capture `self` as `weak` in your blocks.